# Didn't get notified for someone editing my question content

Tags: bug, questions, edits

I am talking about this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799781, where [ryanyuyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu) edited it few mins ago. I didn't get the "Question Edited" by [ryanyuyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu), but I got the notification of comment by [Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki).

This is my notifications screen:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or don't we have any notifications for question edited?

Comment: *Or don't we have any notifications for question edited?* - I want to say I remember getting a notification when one of my posts was edited.

Comment: I believe that edits the [system considers "trivial"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415) (less than about six characters iirc) don't create notifications.